# User.Identity.Name or GetUserName not working on MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an MVC system where I have achieved to put the log in view as the initial page to show (like a splash screen) and once the users have successfully log in redirect them to the main view.

What I need to do next is:

1. One the users are in the main view, there is a section where I try to show the user name. For example: John Smith. To achieve this I'm using the following:

   ```
   User.Identity.Name
   ```

   or

   ```
   User.Identity.GetUserName
   ```

But none of them seems to work. The name is not displayed.
Looking into the tables that were generated when I created my MVC project from VS, `AspNetUser` table doesn't have any column for the Name, last name or full name. Instead it has some columns and one of them is `UserName` which store the data like this: `john.smith`.

So, in order to display the Name and last name of the user should I created extra column on that table and update the register view to enter those kind of data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, in order to store your custom data, you can add extra columns. And in order to access those extra custom columns you can create entities for your AspNetTables and hook them up in DbContext and use accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you have properly set up `ASP .NET Identity` or if you are using project starter template which comes with `ASP .NET Identity` then following should work in the View:

```
@User.Identity.Name

@User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Also If you want to add custom properties to your user then you will have to add those properties to `ApplicationUser` class or any other class inherited by `IdentityUser` and then use that class in `IdentityDbContext`...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

[Check this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#ap)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It works. After looking at the ApplicationUser class I added the properties I needed and did the Code First migration to add those new columns. Also, I complement your answer with the following link (the one that is in the ApplicationUser's comments): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx